# Какая схема хранения дерева в базе подойдет

Tags: mysql

Есть огромная вложенность данных, 12 тыс. записей.

Например есть:

```
category->category1->category1.1->category->1.1.1......и т.д.
```

Могут быть дети, а могут и не быть. Кроме вывода, нужно будет еще сделать поиск. Пробовала использовать Nested Set, построила дерево, в итоге он мне вывел все 12 тыс. записей и *Yii 2* выдал:

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)
```

Даже если я разобью на запросы, что бы не сразу мне выводил все дерево, то как быть с поиском, да и нормальная нагрузка на сервер получается.

Первый раз сталкиваюсь с такой задачей. Какая схема лучше подойдет?

Comment: А пример для этого `category->category1->category1.1->category->1.1.1`  вы можете привести?

Comment: Добавте что у вас до сих пор получилось прямо в вопрос или sqlfiddle.

Comment: Добавьте пример запроса или как Вы пытаетесь получить/обработать записи. Также приведите полный текст ошибки(Exception).

Comment: присоединяюсь к предыдущим комментариям: добавьте код. в частности интересно узнать что именно пошло не так с nested set? каковы требования к поиску?